# Elegant solution for java string custom replacement

Tags: java, regex, string

I solved a problem listed below, it works fine, but seems bulky and not very efficient. I am looking for the ways to improve it and get more elegant solution, any suggestions how can I improve it? Any advices appreciated. Thank you!

Problem:
Given a string, return a string where every appearance of the lowercase word "is" has been replaced with "is not". The word "is" should not be immediately preceded or followed by a letter -- so for example the "is" in "this" does not count.

Tests:

```
    notReplace("is test") → "is not test" 
    notReplace("is-is") → "is not-is not" 
    notReplace("This is right") → "This is not right"
    notReplace("This is isabell") → "This is not isabell" 
    notReplace("")→ ""
    notReplace("is") → "is not" 
    notReplace("isis") → "isis"
    notReplace("Dis is bliss is") → "Dis is not bliss is not"
    notReplace("is his") → "is not his"    
    notReplace("xis yis") → "xis yis" 
    notReplace("AAAis is") → "AAAis is not"
```

My solution:

```
    public static String notReplace(String str) {
    String result="";
    int begin = 0;
    if (str.equals("is"))
         return "is not";
    int index = str.indexOf("is");
    if (index==-1) 
         return str;
    while (index>-1){
          if (index+begin==0 && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index+2))){
              result += "is not";
            begin = index+2; 
            index = str.substring(begin).indexOf("is");
          }
          else if (index+begin==0 && Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index+2))){
              result += str.substring(begin,begin+index)+"is";
              begin += index+2; 
              index = str.substring(begin).indexOf("is");
          }
          else if (index+begin == str.length()-2 && !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index+begin-1))){
              result += str.substring(begin, begin+index)+"is not";
              return result;
          }
          else if(!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index+begin-1))&&!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index+begin+2))){
              result += str.substring(begin,begin+index)+"is not";
              begin += index+2; 
              index = str.substring(begin).indexOf("is");
          }
          else {
              result += str.substring(begin,begin+index)+"is";
              begin += index+2; 
              index = str.substring(begin).indexOf("is");
          }
      }
      result += str.substring(begin);
      return result;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read about so-called "regular expressions". They are commonly used to match and replace input based on certain conditions.

Comment: Thank you for advice @still_learning, I will definitely rewrite my solution with regex, no wonder if there is one line solution, I just didn't have much experience using them yet.

Comment: I would appreciate solutions that works for all mentioned test cases and not only some of them, otherwise suggested solution is not an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Pattern.compile` and then `replaceAll`. I tried to write the `regex` but I failed.

So you should do something like this:

```
class Replacer {
    static Pattern isPattern = Pattern.compile("...(is)..."); // here you have to figure out the right pattern

    public static String notReplace(String input) {
        return isPattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("is not");
    }
}
```

I think that this is the cleanest solution, also much faster than `input.replaceAll` which compiles `Pattern` every time.

As a regular expression probably you should use sth like `[^\\p{Alphanum}](is)[^\\p{Alphanum]`

**UPDATE**

You have to use so called *word boundary* sing `\b` so the expression should look like: `Pattern.compile("\\b(is)\\b")` and that passes all of your tests :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input k0ner, that is what I thought, one thing left is to figure out correct regex.

Comment: see the update. I finally figured out the right regex

Comment: Thanks k0ner, good job, that is exactly what I needed, final code:

public String notReplace(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\bis\\b","is not");
}

Comment: Remember that performance of str.replaceAll is much worse than pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll

Comment: Good! I was so near `(^is | is | is[\\-]|[\\-]is |[^a-zA-Z0-9]is |[^a-zA-Z0-9]?is$)`

Comment: Thanks @k0ner, didn't know that. I was solving the issues on some web site in a browser, where I can't import anything, so it only understands default java classes and I couldn't use the Pattern. Any suggestions on good regex educational source?

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for most of your examples:

```java
public String notReplace(String str) {
    // Add surrounding whitespace in case of an "is" at the beginning or end
    str = " " + str + " ";
    // Do replacement
    String result = str.replaceAll(" is ", " is not ");
    // Other replacements...
    // result = result.replaceAll("", "");

    return result.trim(); // Remove added whitespaces again using trim()
}
```

For the examples that are not being replaced with this code you'll need add some extra lines of code. Or look into regular expressions - as still_learning said.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks regapictures, I appreciate your input, but your solution covers only one scenario for (" is ") case and will fail on all other tests such as "1is", "is+123" and so on. That is not just that simple.

Comment: This is the output I'm getting from my test:
    is not test
    is-is
    This is not right
    This is not isabell

    is not
    isis
    Dis is not bliss is not
    is not his
    xis yis
    AAAis is not

Comment: regapictures, this is correct, but this solution still doesn't handle "is" separated by non white spaces characters.

Comment: You can handle with `$` which means end of line: `result.replaceAll(" is$", " is not")`

Comment: If you want "is-is" to work, you could just add this under "Other replacements", but it's kinda a lazy way: `result = result.replaceAll("-is ", "-is not "); result = result.replaceAll(" is-", " is not-");`

Comment: @regapictures, so you would right this "Other replacements" for all possible scenarios: ("-is"), ("1is"), ("*is"), ("$is") ...? I think you got the idea. Seems like there is no way to solve it besides looping through (what I did) or regex, you can take a look to the accepted answer, it works fine. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: Yes indeed, if you're having much more cases than the ones you mentioned above, it's a bad idea to list them all like I did. Apparently I didn't notice you wanted this to work for ("$is") ("µis") ("*is") and others as well. Glad you found a solution and that I could be of any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for this. The following will return what you specified in your examples:

```
str.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z]|^)is([^a-zA-Z]|$)", "$1is not$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

With @k0ner's help figured out one line solution:

```
public String notReplace(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("\\bis\\b","is not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the given words in your example can arrange with this answer and in case you get something like **"This is not isabell is"** then by this only the last **"is"** will be replaced instead of replacing **"is"** with the **"is not"**.

```
String ss = word.replaceAll("\\bis\\b(?!=*.not\\b)", "is not");
```

Example [link](http://regexr.com/3ca9q)

Comment: thanks for the input, but out of the requirement you will see that first "is" has to be replaced as well (all "is" that are not preceded and followed by letter.)

Comment: You want it like `"This is not isabell is"` - - -> `"This is not not isabell is not"`???

Comment: Yes @Madushan Perera, that is what the author of the problem wants. It's just a practice problem and not a real usage one.